# Java делает паузу на неточное количество миллисекунд

Tags: java, sleep

Есть некое ПО, в котором генерируются события. ПО предоставляет две функции: `GetEvents` и `GetData`. Сценарий такой: сначала выполняется `GetEvents`, проходит какое-то время, после выполняется `GetData`, который возвращает информацию о всех произошедших между вызовом этих двух функций событиях. 
Задача стоит следующая: каждые 15 секунд получать информацию о всех событиях, произошедших за эти 15 секунд. Был написан следующий фрагмент кода на Java:

```
public void fun(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GetEvents();
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(15000);
            System.out.println(GetData());
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

public static void Main(String args[]) {
    for (;;) {
        fun();
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(15000);
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что Java чаще всего делает паузу не ровно на 15000 миллисекунд, а немного больше или меньше (на 15-20 миллисекунд). Из-за этого вывод некоторых событий дублируется, а некоторые не регистрируются вообще. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему? Других функций для получения событий, к сожалению, нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак.

Поток в любое время может быть приостановлен системным планировщиком потоков, так что никаких гарантий нет. Хуже того, спящий поток будет гарантировано приостановлен планировщиком. Гарантии по пробуждению потоков в срок может дать вам лишь real-time OS, которой ваша платформа скорее всего не является.

Переделайте дизайн так, чтобы он не рассчитывал на пробуждение точно в нужный момент.

---

Синхронизация между потоками делается не так. Рассчитывать на таймер нельзя. В Java для таких целей есть синхронизационные примитивы. Например, блок `synchronized`, `Semaphore` или `CyclicBarrier`. Загляните сюда: [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).